# Object assignments in PHP

Tags: php, oop, object

I am a PHP learner. Please help me on the PHP OOP Code below :

```
class x{}
$x = new x; 
$x->name = "Chandan";

class y extends x {}  // Inheritance
$y = new y;

var_dump($x);   // object X; Shows Name property
var_dump($y);   // object y; Empty

$y = $x; 
var_dump($x);   // object X; name = chandan
var_dump($y);   // object X; name = chandan

$x->name = "Debasis";
var_dump($x);   // object X; name = debasis
var_dump($y);   // object X; name = debasis
```

Questions :

1. When we say $x->name = "Chandan"; does it create a public properties? Never seen such assignments in C++.
2. Changes to $x->name is also reflected in $y object.. why? $y = $x should create a copy of $x.

Comment: 1 -> Yes, 2 -> No, No.

Comment: Additional to 2: note the #1 after both var_dumps. It's the same object. Perhaps you want to use [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: X is empty class, so y extends nothing. You dynamically assign value to the object (class is still empty).
You will never see such things like in PHP :D

Comment: I think `1` should also cause some sort of recoverable error. This might be interesting to you: http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we say $x->name = "Chandan"; does it create a public properties?
>   Never seen such assignments in C++.

When you perform:

```
$x = new x; 
$x->name = "Chandan";
```

It creates new instance of `x` class. So, then `$x->name` was assigned only for this instance, not for a class. It's a `public` property, but exists only within `$x` instance.

---

> Changes to $x->name is also reflected in $y object.. why? $y = $x
>   should create a copy of $x.

```
class y extends x {}  // Inheritance
$y = new y;
```

In first row you have declared `y` class, which extends `x`. Class `y` took everything from `x`, but still can not access `x`s private members. It has not inherited `$x->name`, because this property exists within `$x` instance but not within `x` class.

```
$y = $x;
```

`$y` took reference of `$x`. It does not store clone of `$x`, but referes to a place, where it stored. That's why `$y` was affected by this:

```
$x->name = "Debasis";
var_dump($x);   // object X; name = debasis
var_dump($y);   // object X; name = debasis
```

Objects in PHP implicitly always passed by reference. If you need a clone, then you need to explicitly create it with [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword:

```
$y = clone $x;
```

---

Some useful links:

- [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)
- [PHP Object cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)
- [PHP references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a dynamic object:

```
$obj = new STDClass(); //Just a simple container, pretty much like array
$obj->anyStuff = "string" ; //Declare some public variables outside the class.
```

Otherwise you have to declare variables in your class explicitly.

Also, objects are always passed by reference (or assigned), because `$obj` in fact is not an object, it is just a reference, a link to it. The object itself is contained in memory.

`$another = $obj ;` Will just create another reference to the same object.

To clone object you must use:
`$clone = clone $obj` ;

Also you can define a magic method `__clone()` that may be executed when cloning an object.

More info http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Answer (score 0):

If the object definitions confuse you, you can do it differently. I usually structure objects how I do in other languages, the only difference is that you don't have to define a type:

```
class MyClass { 

    // Can use private variables
    private $m_PrivateVar; 
    // Can use protected variables
    protected $m_ProtectedVar;
    // Can use public variables
    public $m_PublicVar

    function __construct()
    {
       // Constructor
    }    
    //etc
}
```

As in response to question 2: Objects are always passed by reference so when passing them in to a function, you aren't creating a copy for that function, it is the same object (like passing pointers to standard variables). The same is true for assignments, your new object $y is infact not a new object any more aftering doing `$y = $x`, it is now a pointer to $x. You will have to manually create a copy/clone function on the object if you wish to make a copy.

Comment: Just saying, in PHP there is `__construct()` as constructor.

Comment: Note that ordinarily nobody "manually create[s] a copy/clone function" they use the language [clone function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)